# Start a new mac terminal window from a groovy script

Tags: groovy, command-line, terminal

Whereas executing a command in a Groovy script file like this:

```
println "ls".execute().text
```

works fine, this command:

```
println "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"ls\"'".execute().text
```

doesn't run! Any idea how to make Groovy launch a new terminal window with a command to run? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
def txt = ['/bin/bash', '-c', /osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "ls"'/].execute().text
println txt
```

But I don't think it does what you want it to, as it prints something along the lines of:

```
tab 1 of window id 38373
```

Comment: Well, the first part does what I want it to do! That printed side affect is benign for what it gives. Will wait to see if there is a better solution; otherwise yours will be. Thank you.